# How do you view a man page you just created?

Tags: manpage

Suppose I have a man page, which I just wrote and passed through `nroff -man`, called `command.1`

How do I view it with `man` now?  I looked though the `man` man page, and maybe I missed it, but I didn't see anything.  I also searched google.

Is it only possible to view using `nroff -man`?  Is there a command line option for `man` to view that specific file?  Is it necessary to modify `MANPATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `command.1` man page in a new folder called `man1`. Then, assuming you're in the folder containing the new `man1` folder, call the man command like this:

```
man -M . command
```

Replace the dot by the path to the folder containing the `man1` folder if you're located elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are different versions of `man` floating around: the one based on the [man-db project](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/man-db) (used in many Linux distros) and the one that comes with macOS, at least as far as I know. I was unable to find a project page for the latter, but it seems to be maintained by Federico Lucifredi.

The main point is this: Lucifredi's `man` supports opening a file directly when providing the path to it with a slash:

```
man ./command.1
```

This is mentioned in the [macOS man page for `man`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/mojave/1/man/):

> However, if *`name`* contains a slash (`/`) then `man` interprets it as a file specification, so that you can do `man ./foo.5` or even `man /cd/foo/bar.1.gz`.

and it's also hinted at in a [blog post by Lucifredi](https://f2.svbtle.com/writing-man-pages):

> One more tip for you:
>
> ```
> man ./foo.1
> ```
>
> is your friend, to see what you just wrote and marked up in all its glory — and bugs.